# How to use static combineLatest correctly

Tags: rxjs, combinelatest

Since `RxJS` v.6.5, the static `combineLatest` syntax 
`combined$ = combineLatest(a$,b$,c$);` is deprecated.

Instead you should use following syntax:

`combined$ = combineLatest([a$,b$,c$])`;

Where they are: `a$: Observable<T>, b$: Observable<U>, c$: Observable<V>`

This declaration although gives me several linting errors:

> Argument type [Observable<ObservableValueOf<Observable<T>>>,
>   Observable<ObservableValueOf<Observable<U>>>,
>   Observable<ObservableValueOf<Observable<V>>>]  is not assignable to
>   parameter type [Observable<ObservableValueOf<Observable<T>>>]

So, where is my error? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you show your code..?

Answer (score 2):

You should import `combineLatest` from `rxjs` instead of `rxjs/operators` like this:

```
import { of, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

const a$ = of(true);
const b$ = of(false);

combineLatest([a$, b$]).pipe(
      tap(console.log)
    ).subscribe();
```

Hope it helps.